# Opayo (SagePay) Pi intergration - Create Transaction API always returns 3DSecure.status = NotChecked

Tags: payment-gateway, opayo, 3d-secure

I am working on Opayo PI integration. https://www.opayolabs.co.uk/apis/pi-api-reference.jsp

According to their new update,(3DSv2)
To create a Transaction I have to send **strongCustomerAuthentication** object.
https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo/spec/api-reference#operation/createTransaction

I try with different data But It always returns

```
{
    "statusCode": "2001",
    "statusDetail": "Transaction rejected by the fraud rules you have in place.",
    "transactionId": "blabla",
    "transactionType": "Payment",
    "status": "Rejected",
    "3DSecure": {
        "status": "NotChecked"
    }
}
```

I tried

```
  "strongCustomerAuthentication": {
    "notificationURL": "https://example.com/",
    "browserIP": "34.201.186.27",
    "browserAcceptHeader": "\\*/\\*",
    "browserJavascriptEnabled": false,
    "browserLanguage": "en",
    "browserUserAgent": "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4",
    "transType": "GoodsAndServicePurchase",
    "challengeWindowSize": "Medium"
  }
```

```
  "strongCustomerAuthentication": {
    "notificationURL": "https://example.com/",
    "browserIP": "<my ip address>",
    "browserAcceptHeader": "\\*/\\*",
    "browserJavascriptEnabled": false,
    "browserLanguage": "en",
    "browserUserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0",
    "transType": "GoodsAndServicePurchase",
    "challengeWindowSize": "Small"
  }
```

Do anyone knows What is the correct data for this object?

My expected response for a challenge authentication outcome

```
{
  "statusCode":"2021",
  "statusDetail":"Please redirect your customer to the ACSURL to complete the 3DS Transaction",
  "transactionId":"BEB718F6-3ED2-323E-2CB2-B8C83DB2029C",
  "acsTransId":"43b04fd1-692c-4b76-ac20-a75527ad0a25",
  "dsTransId":"7980e36f-907b-4530-84fd-ccc1f40bf9ae",
  "acsUrl":"https://localhost:8252/html_challenge",
  "status":"3DAuth",
  "cReq":"eyJtZXNzYWdlVHlwZSI6IkNSZXEi...V2luZG93U2l6ZSI6IjAxIn0"
}
```

https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo/3d-secure-authentication#challenge-authentication

Comment: Fixed - There was a setting issue in account.

Comment: Did you by any chance find out what that setting was?

Comment: No, I sent a mail to support, They found the issue and fixed

Answer (score 0):

give cardholder name = CHALLENGE

while filling form.
The securityCode (CV2/CVV) is always: 123 (1234 for Amex cards)
The billingAddress.address1 is: 88
The billingAddress.postalCode is: 412
Any expiryDate can be entered as long as it is in the future
Hope this will helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).